# Can anyone identify this sword guard?

Tags: identification, sword

I dug this sword guard while I was metal detecting at a Revolutionary War site.  I have been researching for days and asking for assistance on other forums but I have not had any success.  I would like to identify this sword guard.[image]

[image]

[image]

I would like to know who made it and which side.

Comment: In what way would you want to identify it? Whom did it belong to? Who made it ? Which side was it? Please specify

Comment: That looks suspiciously like George III in profile in the middle picture.  I would also doubt that this would have been a standard issue.  What site was it recovered from?  There might be some hints there.

Comment: I would like to know who made it and which side......Thanks

Comment: more details would indeed be needed. Where was it found, what else around it that can help date the artifact, things like that.

Comment: And questions like this are the exact reason why the digging up of old artefacts should be left to archaeologists instead of treasure hunters. Location, site and exact situation of the find are crucial, and this information is now in large parts lost... What remains is not a piece of history, but an old, oxidised lump of metal.

Answer (score -3):

It certainly looks like the hand guard of a British saber, and judging by the imprint and the flat inner side of the guard, it probably belonged to an officer (usually, only officers or calvary had sabers) of either the Royal Army or the Field Army. That's my two cents.

Comment: Posting an image or two to help support your case would improve this answer.